# tuple of strings "is" comparison behaves inconsistently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused.

```
foo = ("empty", 0)
foo[0] is "empty"
```

Returns False. This seems to be a problem with keyword strings, as "list" fails as well. "empt" and other strings return true. This only seems to happen with tuples, as if foo is a list the code also returns true

I've tested this with python 3.4.3 and python 3.5 and both behave this way, python2.7 doesn't seem to have this issue though and returns true as expected.

Am I missing some standard on tuples in python3? I've attempted to google-foo this problem but am coming up short.

**Edit:
To clear things up, my exact question is why does**

```
foo = ("empty", 0)
foo[0] is "empty"
```

return False, but

```
foo = ("empt", 0)
foo[0] is "empt"
```

return True?

Comment: You're *comparing strings*. Why did you decide to use `is` and not `==`?

Comment: Because the two are not literally the same object, which is what `is` tests for. They are *equal.*

Comment: `t = ("list",); t[0] is "list"` evalutes to `False` and `t = ("notlist",); t[0] is "notlist"` to `True`. I think this is the core of the question.

Comment: @kalsi Please make the core of your question more clear **and prominent**. People are downvoting your question because they think you simply mixed up `==` and `is`.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with Python 3.3 but not on 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers already mentioned: You are comparing strings by identity and this is likely to fail. Assumptions about the identity of string literals can not be made.

However, you actually found a subtle issue.

```
>>> t = ("list",); t[0] is "list"
False
>>> t = ("notlist",); t[0] is "notlist"
True
>>> t = ("list",)
>>> id(t[0])
140386135830064
>>> id("list")
140386137208400
>>> t[0] is "list"
False
>>> l = ("notlist",)
>>> id(l[0])
140386135830456
>>> id("notlist")
140386135830456
>>> l[0] is "notlist"
True
# interestingly, this works:
>>> ("list",)[0] is "list"
True
```

*(Tested with Python 3.5.1+ interactive shell)*

This is plainly implementation-dependent behavior by some component of python, presumably lexer or parser.

Bottom-line: Use `==` for string comparison, as long as you do not depend on object identity.

Comment: You assume correctly; there is no reason to expect `("list",)[0] is "list"` to be true, either. An interpreter is free to allocate separate objects for each literal.

Comment: "subtle issue" - nope, not an issue. Python makes no promises that this behavior would violate.

Comment: Do you have a better word for this behavior? I know that this is no violation. However, it is not very intuitive, as a string *containing* a python keyword seems nothing special.

Comment: Neat, the behavior seemed to be dependent on keywords or something. Good to know this falls into the undefined territory with is comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
a is b
```

Equals to

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

As mentioned here [Comparing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)
Also read this 
[Built-in Functions - id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

Answer (score 0):

Using a literal value with `is` is almost certainly going to give you an implementation-dependent result. The only literal that Python guarantees to be a singleton is `None`. Any other literal may or may not resolve to a reference to an existing object. You can't assume that the interpreter will "recognize" the duplicate value and use the same underlying object to represent it.